# Why am I way off with distance calculation between latitude and longitude?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, dax, distance

Can anybody please tell me why I am way off?  I am working on getting distance between two points on Power BI /Excel. I did my research online and  I found a very common formula used by everyone.  So  tested it out, my distance is way off. Please see below, 
[image]

The distance between Logan and Draper is 111 miles, but I am getting 3750 miles. 
I hard coded the formula to test it out. I know this is not 100% accurate, but I am completely off.

```
 Orginal formula =ACOS(SIN(Lat1)*SIN(Lat2) +COS(Lat1)*COS(Lat2)*COS(Lon2-Lon1)) *3958.756

My hard coded one = COS(SIN(40.51)*SIN(41.73) +COS(40.51)*COS(41.73)*COS(-111.78-(-111.87))) *3958.756
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up from the previous answer, you need to convert your latitude and longitude to radians.

Following the formula from [this website](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) I get the same results in DAX of 134.9 km. The site has a calculator, from which I get the same result in DAX.

```
Distance = 

var _lat1 = RADIANS(40.524670)
var _lon1 = RADIANS(-111.863823)
var _lat2 = RADIANS(41.7379)
var _lon2 = RADIANS(-111.8308)

var R = 6371

var _dif1 = (_lat2 - _lat1)
var _dif2 = (_lon2 - _lon1)

var _a = (sin(_dif1/2)^2) + cos(_lat1) * cos(_lat2) * (sin(_dif2/2) ^ 2)

var _c  =  2*ASIN(SQRT(_a))

return _c * R
```

Answer (score 1):

In your searches you may have seen this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula), but just in case I'm offering it.

Right off the bat, I do not see any use of Pi in your formula which makes me wonder if you've converted your latitudes to radians.  When I did a quick, dirty, back of the napkin calc and converted the lats to be expressed in rads then the answer came out much closer (error probably due to my horrific rounding of PI/180.

[This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-distance-two-points-earth/) site may also be of use.

I hope I've at least pointed you in the right direction to get it going.

Comment: Can you please share how did you calculate it? I have note converted to radians. I would appreciate if you share it. I look at your site too. It just the same formula tho. I want to run thin in excel, ideally power bi. Please share how you calculated.  Thank you